# How to display a list obtained through web service using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Can I use an array to show the data obtained from a web service, and show them in a listview?

This is a snippet of my code:

```
class WSResult2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string equipment { get; set; }
    public string serial { get; set; }
}

class WSResultList
{
    public List<WSResult2> items { get; set; }
}
```

Page4.xaml.cs:

```
private async Task wsvarAsync(Result result)
    {
        WSClient client = new WSClient();

        string wUrl = "--Here is the url of the web service--" + result.Text + "&option=2";

        var resultws = await client.Get<WSResultList>(wUrl);


        if (resultws != null)
        { //I want to know how to use an array here to get the complete list of each of the items captured by the web service.
            lblEquipment.Text = resultws.items[0].equipment;
            lblSerial.Text = resultws.items[0].serial;
            lblurl.Text = resultws.items[0].url;

        }
    }
```

Page4.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout Padding="20">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btnScan" Text="Read code" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" CornerRadius="25" Clicked="btnScan_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <Label x:Name="lblInfo" />

    <Label Text="Equipment: " TextColor="Red"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblEquipment" />

    <Label Text="Serial: " TextColor="Red"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblSerial" />
    <!-- I want to know how to use a Binding to show all the data captured from the web service. -->
    <Label IsVisible="False" Text="Report: " TextColor="Red"/>
    <Label IsVisible="False" x:Name="lblurl" />
    <Button x:Name="btnUrl" Text="See report"  Clicked="OnButtonClicked" CornerRadius="25" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="Red"/>

</StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

WSClient.cs is the client to deserialize the JSON:

```
class WSClient
{
    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }

    public async Task<T> Post<T>(string pUrl, T pData)
    {
        var wJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pData);
        var wData = new StringContent(wJsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var wResponse = await client.PostAsync(pUrl, wData);
        var json = await wResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the array data in a ListView?

Comment: @Jhon117 Can you try to replace your code using `List<WSResult2> items = await client.Get<List<WSResult2>>(wUrl);`, then you will get List<WSResult2> items, you can display data using ListView.

Answer (score 0):

**Page4.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="ResultList">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout>
               <Label Text="{Binding url }"/>
                </StackLayout>

        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate></ListView>
```

**Page4.xaml.cs**

```
private async Task wsvarAsync(Result result)
    {
        WSClient client = new WSClient();


        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(wUrl);
        var resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WSResultList>>(json)

        //to view each item on debug
        for(var i = 0; i < resultList i++){
            Console.WriteLine(resultList[i].equipment);
        }

        //populate the list view to visualize your data
        ResulitList.ItemSource = resultList;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @RyanMotal, but it did not work for me, add to the description of the question the code that I use as a client, where I deserialize the Json. I get thirty errors in: 'GetStringAsync', in 'resultListl' and 'ResulitList.ItemSource'.

Error CS1061 'WSClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetStringAsync'
Error CS0103 The name 'ResulitList' does not exist in the current context
Error CS0103 The name 'item' does not exist in the current context
Error CS0103 The name 'ResulitList' does not exist in the current context